# Jersey Spring Integration and Scopes

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I try Spring and Jersey integration.But I'm confused about scopes.
For spring the default scope is Singleton.
And for Jersey default scope is Request.

For example:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

 // The Java class will be hosted at the URI path "/myresource"
 @Path("/myresource")
 @Component
 @Scope("request")

 public class MyResource {

   // The Java method will process HTTP GET requests
   @GET
   // The Java method will produce content identified by the MIME Media
   // type "text/plain"
   @Produces("text/plain")
   public String getIt() {
       return "Hi there!";
   }
}
```

Component annotation makes the class a Spring Bean.Spring bean is default Singleton and jersey is default request scope.

Here is the question: What is the scope for this bean.

- If I put @Scope("request") does it make "request scope".
- And if I don't put @Scope("request") what is the actual scope?

Answer (score 3):

As you said, you make `MyResource` a Spring Bean, so the scope is handled by Spring.

- **With @Scope("request") :** the scope of your bean will be "request"
- **Without @Scope("request") :** the scope of your bean will be "singleton" (spring default)

Whether you use CXF or Jersey with Spring, these are only used for the JAX-RS endpoints programming (not for managing beans).

**EDIT** : I've found it in the documentation:

> Since the Endpoint is a Spring @Component its lifecycle is managed by
>   Spring and you can @Autowired dependencies and inject external
>   configuration with @Value. The Jersey servlet will be registered and
>   mapped to /* by default. You can change the mapping by adding
>   @ApplicationPath to your ResourceConfig.

link: [27.2 JAX-RS and Jersey](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jersey)